# Acknowledging math stack exchange

Tags: discussion, advice

If we get answers for our doubts from this site  can we acknowledge math stack exchange or for that matter the author who has responded to our doubts?

Comment: This question is clearly not suitable for math.SE.  It appears to be about math.SE, making it suitable for meta.math.SE.  But I'm not certain exactly what you mean by "acknowledging" math.SE (or its users).  (Do you mean citing math.SE posts in other media?)

Comment: yes, or can we write "author thanks math stack exchange for the useful suggestions" some thing like that

Comment: i.e., if our doubts got cleared from math stack exchange

Comment: But what's the context? are we talking about publishing papers in research journals? about handing in homework in trigonometry? about proposing to our girlfriends?

Comment: Note also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961/how-do-you-cite-math-stack-exchange-pages-in-scientific-papers?

Comment: Note also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10824/how-to-acknowledge-math-stack-exchange?

Comment: Perhaps also some other questions tagged ([meta-tag:citation]). (I would consider adding the tag to this question, but it is somewhat unclear, so I am not sure.)

Comment: When you thank your professor, do you think him personally, or the university? When you cite a paper, do you cite the paper and the author or the journal?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think the OP means referencing a specific thread rather than all of MSE. (I do agree that the latter is rather silly!)

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why you *can't* acknowledge MSE for anything. Credit where credit is due!

The real question is *should* you acknowledge MSE. If the context is research that gained significant inspiration or other advantage from an MSE thread, then an acknowledgement is probably in order, and I believe the appropriate procedure in this case has been well discussed on meta. (See Gerry's links.)

If the context is homework, use your best judgement. Very commonly professors ask that you give credit where credit is due if you received outside assistance on a problem, and in this case you should consider acknowledging MSE.

If the context is proposing to your girlfriend, use your *very* best judgement.

Acknowledging a specific user is more tricky, and you may want to ask for permission from the user first.

Comment: Technically speaking, the user who posted the answer has already  agreed to the answer being used [with attribution](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). One should probably still ask about the desired form of attribution: as user937462, or by name, etc.